# Fluid layout: aside element larger than main element

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am trying to float my aside element to the right of my main element and for some reason it is too large. I specified the width of the main as 60% and the aside as 39% (because the body element is 99%) but somehow this ratio is just not displayed correctly.

Here is the html and css:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  background: url("/images/sheetmusic.gif") repeat 0 0;
  background-size: 30%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

body {
  font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  width: 99%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: rgba(255, 248, 228, 0.95);
  border: 2px solid #585858;
}

a:link {
  color: #e07400;
}

a:visited {
  color: gray;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  font-style: italic;
}


/*====================HEADER========================*/

header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 136.078px;
}

.orange_header {
  color: #e07400;
}

header h1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-shadow: 2px 1px 1px black;
  padding-top: 0.7em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5em;
}


/*====================NAV MENU========================*/

#nav_menu a {
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid silver;
}

#nav_menu a.current {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  background-color: #a78349;
}

#nav_menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;
}

#nav_menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  width: 20.748125%;
  /* 165.985/800*100 */
}

#nav_menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ab6b06;
  color: white;
}

#nav_menu ul ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

#nav_menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
}

#nav_menu ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block
}

#nav_menu>ul::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}

#lastmenuitem {
  border: none;
}


/*====================MAIN========================*/

main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

main h2 {
  font-size: 150%;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}

strong {
  color: #ab6b06;
}

main p {
  font-size: 100%;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

main ul,
ol {
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: .5em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}


/*=============ASIDE====================*/

aside {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 39%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-left: 2px solid #ab6b06;
}

aside h3 {
  font-size: 120%;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

aside>p {
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#sittingpic {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

blockquote {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: .5em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.image {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 2%;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

.image img {
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 150px;
}

iframe {
  padding-left: 2em;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 720px;
}


/*====================FOOTER========================*/

footer {
  background-color: #ab6b06;
  font-family: georgia, serif;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Annemie's Guitar School | Learn Classical Guitar</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <img src="images/guitarlogo2.png" alt="Guitar" height="109.93">
    <h1 class="orange_header">Annemie's Guitar School</h1>
  </header>
  <nav id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="useful_links.html">Useful links</a></li>
      <li><a href="lesson_intro.html">Lessons</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="sittingpos.html">Sitting position</a></li>
          <li><a href="readingmusic.html">Reading music</a></li>
          <li><a href="rhtech.html">Right Hand Technique</a></li>
          <li><a href="lhtech.html">Left Hand Technique</a></li>
          <li><a href="pracandmem.html">Practising and Memorization</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="bio.html" id="lastmenuitem">Bio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <aside>
      <h3>History of the guitar</h3>
      <p>In this documentary, Julian Bream walks you through the history of the classical guitar in Spain. He plays pieces that are relevant to the different eras of the guitar. Although the documentary is fairly slow paced - it is worth the watch! <br>
        <a href="video.html">Watch video</a>
      </p>
      <h3>Anatomy of the guitar</h3>
      <img src="images/clas-diagram.jpg" alt="Guitar Diagram" class="image" height="300">
      <h3>Quote of the day</h3>
      <blockquote>&ldquo;Sometimes you want to give up the guitar, you&rsquo;ll hate the guitar. But if you stick with it, you&rsquo;re gonna be rewarded&rdquo; ~<cite> Jimi Hendrix</cite></blockquote>
    </aside>

    <h2 class="orange_header">Classical Guitar</h2>
    <p>The guitar is arguably the most popular and versatile instrument in the world. It is used in a variety of different musical styles like rock, blues, folk and pop. <strong>This school focusses on the classical style of playing. </strong> With classical
      guitar you use nylon strings and play all the voices (bass, alto, soprano) using a special right hand technique. The guitar becomes a &ldquo;mini orchestra&rdquo;.</p>

    <h2 class="orange_header">Before you start...</h2>
    <p>This school requires you to know a few basics before you can start the lessons. <br>We assume that you can:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Tune your guitar</li>
      <li>Play chords comfortably</li>
      <li>Read tablature</li>
    </ul>
    <p>If you can&lsquo;t do these things - do not worry!<br> We suggest you make use of the <a href="useful_links.html">&ldquo;Useful links&rdquo;</a> page to teach yourself the basics of guitar.</p>
    <h2 class="orange_header">The Lessons</h2>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="sittingpos.html">Sitting position</a></li>
      <li><a href="readingmusic.html">Reading music</a></li>
      <li><a href="rhtech.html">Right Hand Technique</a></li>
      <li><a href="lhtech.html">Left Hand Technique</a></li>
      <li><a href="pracandmem.html">Practising and Memorization</a></li>
    </ol>
    <h2 class="orange_header">About Annemie</h2>
    <p>Find out more about the author of this site by going to <a href="bio.html">the Bio page.</a></p>

  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy;2017, Annemie's Guitar School</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the concept of widths. You set the `width` of `main` to `60%`. This will cover only the `60%` of the `body` tag. You also set the `width` of `aside` to `39%`, but this element is parent to `main`. That means that it will cover the `39%` of the `main` container. I don't know if I understood your question (I don't have the reputation right now to ask for more details with comments) so I consider you want something like the following (excuse my bad drawing skills):

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNDmX.png)

I propose to make the following changes:

First create a new `div` element (I named it `main-content`) and add the left floating content inside it.

```
<main>
    <aside>
      <h3>History of the guitar</h3>
      <p>In this documentary, Julian Bream walks you through the history of the classical guitar in Spain. He plays pieces that are relevant to the different eras of the guitar. Although the documentary is fairly slow paced - it is worth the watch! <br>
        <a href="video.html">Watch video</a>
      </p>
      <h3>Anatomy of the guitar</h3>
      <img src="images/clas-diagram.jpg" alt="Guitar Diagram" class="image" height="300">
      <h3>Quote of the day</h3>
      <blockquote>“Sometimes you want to give up the guitar, you’ll hate the guitar. But if you stick with it, you’re gonna be rewarded” ~<cite> Jimi Hendrix</cite></blockquote>
    </aside>

  <!-- the newly created div -->
  <div id="main-content">
    <h2 class="orange_header">Classical Guitar</h2>
    <p>The guitar is arguably the most popular and versatile instrument in the world. It is used in a variety of different musical styles like rock, blues, folk and pop. <strong>This school focusses on the classical style of playing. </strong> With classical
      guitar you use nylon strings and play all the voices (bass, alto, soprano) using a special right hand technique. The guitar becomes a “mini orchestra”.</p>

    <h2 class="orange_header">Before you start...</h2>
    <p>This school requires you to know a few basics before you can start the lessons. <br>We assume that you can:</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Tune your guitar</li>
      <li>Play chords comfortably</li>
      <li>Read tablature</li>
    </ul>
    <p>If you can‘t do these things - do not worry!<br> We suggest you make use of the <a href="useful_links.html">“Useful links”</a> page to teach yourself the basics of guitar.</p>
    <h2 class="orange_header">The Lessons</h2>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="sittingpos.html">Sitting position</a></li>
      <li><a href="readingmusic.html">Reading music</a></li>
      <li><a href="rhtech.html">Right Hand Technique</a></li>
      <li><a href="lhtech.html">Left Hand Technique</a></li>
      <li><a href="pracandmem.html">Practising and Memorization</a></li>
    </ol>
    <h2 class="orange_header">About Annemie</h2>
    <p>Find out more about the author of this site by going to <a href="bio.html">the Bio page.</a></p>
  </div>
  <!-- new div ends here -->


  </main>
```

Then change your css style to this:

```
/* we removed the width property to cover the whole page. */
main {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

aside {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 40%; /* this was changed */
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-left: 2px solid #ab6b06;
}

#main-content {
  width: 60%; 
}
```

Comment: Oh dear..it seems I have yet another problem regarding this page layout..I made a small change: I coded my Aside element AFTER my main element so that the main element will stay at the top when I resize my browser window to a smaller size. Now the aside element just spills over and outside the body element..what to do?

Comment: @A.Burger create a new post. Add the appropriate information there and a screenshot. This is a different question and is not related to this one. After you doing it, we'll be able to answer. :)